# Jupyter Notebooks in Zeppelin

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, apache-zeppelin

Is there any solution to run Jupyter widgets (in python) in Zeppelin? I have some notebooks in Jupyter and implemented by Jupyter widgets and I am seeking a solution to move the notebooks to Zeppelin.